# how do you convert to_char to datetime format in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to retrieve data for last 5 minutes from an oracle table:

```
SELECT to_char(a.collection_timestamp, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS') collection_timestamp
  FROM table_name
 WHERE collection_timestamp > SYSDATE - 5 / 1440
```

I get results older than 5 minutes ago. Do I have to convert to COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP into oracle datetime? How?

```
select sysdate from dual

17-FEB-15

Desc <table name>
COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP  DATE
```

This is what I get when I execute that query:

```
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:33
17-02-2015 12:02:29
17-02-2015 12:02:24
17-02-2015 12:02:24
17-02-2015 12:02:24
17-02-2015 12:02:24
17-02-2015 12:02:24
17-02-2015 12:02:24
17-02-2015 12:02:41
17-02-2015 12:02:07
17-02-2015 12:02:29
17-02-2015 12:02:17
17-02-2015 12:02:17
17-02-2015 12:02:17
17-02-2015 12:02:17
```

current time is 12:43

Comment: It seems to me that it's the filtering part of your SQL - the where clause - that you should be focusing on, not the conversion of the timestamp to a string. Once you've got the rows you want, *then* you can worry about how you select values from them.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `where COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` btw? That looks a lot clearer to me than the `-5/1440` bit...

Comment: @JonSkeet, at the beginnin of the  sql, I converting to_char, dont you think I have cast that back to datetime to use in where clause?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I tried COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP >SYSDATE - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE, I still get data from 30 minutes ago. I need to get last 5 minutes data.

Comment: No, why would you need to? I suggest you change it to `select *` for the moment, just to completely take everything else out of the equation.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I keep getting data older than last five minutes.

Comment: What is the type of `COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP`, and are you sure the database time is correct?

Comment: Yes, I understand that the filter isn't matching what you want, and I'm trying to help you with that - but I'm suggesting it's got nothing to do with the `select` clause, and using `select *` will make that more obvious. It would really help if you'd show us some sample data, the schema, and an example of `select sysdate from dual` alongside some results taken at the same time.

Comment: @JonSkeet, just update some more data in the post. I do appreciate your help, I cannot just figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps consider using `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE`? It's not clear to me why SYSDATE is only returning a date rather than a date and time...#

Comment: If Boneist's answer is correct, then using `select *` as I suggested would have found the problem a lot earlier...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a format of: `'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'`

Change that to: `'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MI:SS'`

Your where clause will be restricting the data to the last five minutes, but you're displaying the minutes part of your date-time as the month number.

Comment: @user1471980 - you almost certainly want to make it `HH24` instead of just `HH` too, otherwise you can't tell 3am from 3pm. [Read more about the date and time format model elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Comment: Good spot, @Alex! I missed that one! Ah well, 1 out of 2 ain't bad! *{;-)